# I am trying to import this simpletransformers got the error

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, simpletransformers

```
from simpletransformers.question_answering import QuestionAnsweringModel
```

got this attribute error:

AttributeError: module 'urllib3.util' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLS'

Answer (score 1):

Using `!pip freeze` solved the issue

Comment: This was solved a similar error in homeassistant package installation too